# How to configure multible CA certs in git?

Tags: git, ssl-certificate, self-signed, ca

I currently have a situation where I need a (self generated) RootCA.crt configured for our internal private gitlab installation.

At the same time we still need "normal" access to github.com.

Therefore I need both CA settings working at the same time.

My `git config --global --edit` looks like this

```
[user]
        name = my name
        email = my email
[core]
        autocrlf = false
        excludesfile = C:\\Users\\<user>\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        process = git-lfs filter-process
        required = true
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
        cmd = 'C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe' \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -o \"$MERGED\"
        trustExitCode = true
[winUpdater]
        recentlySeenVersion = 2.17.0.windows.1
[credential]
        helper = store
[http "https://our.gitlab.server*"]
        sslVerify = true
        sslCAInfo = C:/ssl/RootCA.crt
        sslCAPath = C:/ssl
[http "https://github.com*"]
        sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
        sslCAPath = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs
        sslVerify = true
```

So as you can see I configured the two http entries, one for our local server and one for github. (like shown in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#EXAMPLES))

If I am just setting one at a time like

```
[http]
     sslCAInfo = C:/ssl/RootCA.crt
     sslCAPath = C:/ssl/
     sslVerify  = true
```

the according repos work fine.

But in the moment using the upper config it is always showing nothing:

```
$ git config --get-all http.sslCAInfo
(nothing)
```

**How can I get both configurations using different CA certs according to the repositories URL to work properly?**

Comment: I have not fussed with any of the CA-cert stuff in Git but I can note here, as a quick comment, that `--get-all http.sslCAInfo` looks for `http.sslCAInfo` and not `http.<whatever>.sslCAInfo`. You can use `--get-regexp` to search using regular expressions (where this is `http\..*\.sslCAInfo`).

Comment: Yeah the problem in general with that `http.<whatever>.sslCAInfo` seems to be that git simply doesn't recognize it as the place where to look for the CAs ...

Answer (score 1):

As a kind of workarround I opened the default
`C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` and my `C:/ssl/RootCA.crt` in a text editor and appended the content of the default CA-cert bundle to mine so it now contains all certs.

Anyway I hoped there would be an esier way to do it because now with every git update I have to make sure the CA-certs which I copied from the default are still valid. And if not everyone using our internal git has to replace his cert file again.